# VBA path of the file from a dialog box file picker which would include: specific worksheet + range of cells on this sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon! I need to create a VBA code which would open a dialog box to pick up a file, then it will get file path which would include specific worksheet which is fixed and called "new rates" and range of cells which is also fixed - from A:AP or R2C1:R1048576C42. In order to eliminate user mistakes worksheet and range should be fixed . Further this file path would be used as a pivot source for pivot tables.

Now, I have created a VBA macro which allows me to get a file path without worksheet and cells range in it. Example is shown below:

"https://sharepoint.com/sites/SharedDocuments/2021/08_Aug/Name_08_2021.xlsb"

So, as it doesn't include worksheet + cells of range it cannot be used for pivot source, that's why I need to get the ouput like this:

"https://sharepoint.com/sites/SharedDocuments/2021/08_Aug/[Name_08_2021.xlsb]name_of_the_worksheet'!R2C1:R1048576C42"

Below there is a code which I've managed to write. I would really appreciate your help! Thank you in advance.

```
Sub PivotSource()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, pivot As PivotTable, cache As PivotCache
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant, OpenBook As Workbook
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Choose file to for pivot tables", MultiSelect:=False, FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*),*xls*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    Else
    MsgBox "File is not selected"
    End If
         
    MsgBox "Workbook was opened, starting to update source data...", vbInformation
    
    ThisWorkbook.Activate

  Set cache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, SourceData:=*link will be here*) 
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pivot In ws.PivotTables
      If cache.Index Then
        pivot.CacheIndex = cache.Index
      Else
        pivot.ChangePivotCache cache
      End If
    Next
  Next

  cache.Refresh
  
    MsgBox "Source was changed for all pivot tables", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Once you've opened the file you'll need to prompt the user to select the range containing the data - you can use `InputBox` for that.  https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-to-select-range-with-inputbox

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for your answer! I forgot to mention that worksheet and range is fixed. So, worksheet is called "new rates" and range is from A:AP or R2C1:R1048576C42. In order to eliminate user mistakes worksheet and range should be fixed. So, is it possible to do this withoyt prompting user to select the range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the worksheet name and source range are known in advance then you should be able to do something like this:

```vb
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Choose file to for pivot tables", _
                 MultiSelect:=False, FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*),*xls*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    Else
        MsgBox "File is not selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If
         
    MsgBox "Workbook was opened, starting to update source data...", vbInformation
    
    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    Set cache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
              XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, _
              SourceData:=OpenBook.Worksheets("DataSheet").Range("A2:AP1048576"))
```